# javascript onkeydown not working in numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem while entering the number values from the Num pad.My script is only accepting numbers from the number keys above the 'qwerty' keys. What I want is that user can also enter numbers from numeric keypad. Following is the HTML:

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;background-color:#E5E4E2;">
     <input type="text" name="qty_enter[]"  id="qty_enter0" onkeyup="sum(0),itc_details(0),prevent_zero(0),advance_seeting1();" onkeypress="copyValue2(1)" onkeydown="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width: 65px;outline: none;border: none; background: transparent;"/>
</td>
```

However I tried to call the script on onkeypress and onkeyup functions but it's not working because I have already called function over there. Here is the script below for only accepting numerical values. 
Also I have double checked the Num Lock and that's not the issue.

```
<script>
    function isNumberKey(evt)
           {
              var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
              if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
                && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                 return false;

              return true;
           }
    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Because num lock is off

Comment: Your first step, as always, should be to **debug**. The key codes received by `keyup` and `keydown` for the numeric keypad are *different* from those received for the main keyboard. If you'd used the powerful debugger built into your browser, you would have seen that almost immediately.

Comment: I have double checked that, that's not that issue, otherwise i wouldn't had posted the question..@Lissy

Comment: I have a weird issue with the num lock. It is reversed. I think it is because I'm working remotely (via TeamViewer). Local machine, perfectly fine. Remote machine, reversed num lock. Maybe that helps anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Because numlock numbers keycode is different normal number keys.

> Ex  keycode 48=number 0, when Numlock 0 = keycode 96;

[Look  this article](http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm) .

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  console.log("KeyCode: "+charCode);
  if (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 106 )
      console.log("Numlock number detected: "+charCode);
}
```

```html
<td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;background-color:#E5E4E2;">
     <input type="text" name="qty_enter[]"  id="qty_enter0"  onkeydown="isNumberKey(event)" style="width: 65px;"/>
</td>
```

Comment: You are saying that i should add the numlock number keycode condition in the if block too

Comment: Yes , check answer i updated . You can see different, numlock numbers vs qwert numbers. @shubhamdahibhate

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). @shubhamdahibhate

Answer (score 0):

Your function is actually written to block the num pad from entering any key.
Reverse the return false with true and vice versa to enable nums but disable letters and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got answer for my question after 3-4 days long.  Script was ok.  It was pretty simple I just changed event as shown in below.

```
<input type="text" name="qty_enter[]"  id="qty_enter0" onkeyup="sum(0),itc_details(0),prevent_zero(0),advance_seeting1();" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeydown="copyValue2(1)" style="width: 65px;outline: none;border: none; background: transparent;"/>
```